# Cannot inject resource

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, osgi, bundle, cdi

I'm using Glassfish 4 with latest JSF version. I want to use resource injection and @Resource in order to use database resource.

```
@Named("LoginController")
@SessionScoped
public class UserCheck implements Serializable
{
    @Resource(name = "jdbc/Oracle")
    private DataSource ds;

    @Inject
    @OSGiService(dynamic = true, waitTimeout = 5)
    transient SessionHandle SH;


.....
}
```

For some reason I get this error message:

```
[2014-01-30T21:32:34.517+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] [tid: _ThreadID=84 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(1)] [timeMillis: 1391110354517] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Error Rendering View[/Home.xhtml]
com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean LoginController
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.injectResources(BeanBuilder.java:209)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:257)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:117)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:116)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getBase(AstValue.java:151)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:200)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:174)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getValue(UIInput.java:291)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:461)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.DX_57.SR_57.HttpLoginFilter.doFilter(HttpLoginFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderException: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting to inject Res-Ref-Env-Property: jdbc/Oracle@javax.sql.DataSource@ resolved as: jndi: java:comp/DefaultDataSource@res principal: null@mail: null
No Runtime properties
Database Vendor : null
Create Tables at Deploy : false
Delete Tables at Undeploy : false into class com.DX_57.SR_57.UserCheck: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/jdbc/Oracle' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
    at org.glassfish.faces.integration.GlassFishInjectionProvider.inject(GlassFishInjectionProvider.java:194)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.injectResources(BeanBuilder.java:203)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting to inject Res-Ref-Env-Property: jdbc/Oracle@javax.sql.DataSource@ resolved as: jndi: java:comp/DefaultDataSource@res principal: null@mail: null
No Runtime properties
Database Vendor : null
Create Tables at Deploy : false
Delete Tables at Undeploy : false into class com.DX_57.SR_57.UserCheck: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/jdbc/Oracle' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:717)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:484)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.injectInstance(InjectionManagerImpl.java:170)
    at org.glassfish.faces.integration.GlassFishInjectionProvider.inject(GlassFishInjectionProvider.java:184)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/jdbc/Oracle' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/DefaultDataSource' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, com.sun.enterprise.naming.logicalName=java:comp/env/jdbc/Oracle} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'jdbc/__default' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: __default not found]]]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:613)
    ... 68 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/DefaultDataSource' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, com.sun.enterprise.naming.logicalName=java:comp/env/jdbc/Oracle} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'jdbc/__default' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: __default not found]]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.util.JndiNamingObjectFactory.create(JndiNamingObjectFactory.java:90)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.util.JndiInitializationNamingObjectFactory.create(JndiInitializationNamingObjectFactory.java:110)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:745)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:715)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:159)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:471)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'jdbc/__default' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: __default not found]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at org.glassfish.jdbcruntime.DefaultDataSource.handle(DefaultDataSource.java:69)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.NamedNamingObjectManager.tryNamedProxies(NamedNamingObjectManager.java:134)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:164)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:471)
    ... 81 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: __default not found
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.doLookup(TransientContext.java:237)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:204)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:208)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:66)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:478)
    ... 88 more
]]

[2014-01-30T21:32:34.533+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=84 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(1)] [timeMillis: 1391110354533] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: __default not found
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.doLookup(TransientContext.java:237)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:204)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:208)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:66)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:478)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at org.glassfish.jdbcruntime.DefaultDataSource.handle(DefaultDataSource.java:69)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.NamedNamingObjectManager.tryNamedProxies(NamedNamingObjectManager.java:134)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:164)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:471)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.util.JndiNamingObjectFactory.create(JndiNamingObjectFactory.java:90)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.util.JndiInitializationNamingObjectFactory.create(JndiInitializationNamingObjectFactory.java:110)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:745)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:715)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:159)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:471)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:613)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:484)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.injectInstance(InjectionManagerImpl.java:170)
    at org.glassfish.faces.integration.GlassFishInjectionProvider.inject(GlassFishInjectionProvider.java:184)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.injectResources(BeanBuilder.java:203)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:257)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:117)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:116)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getBase(AstValue.java:151)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:200)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:174)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getValue(UIInput.java:291)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:461)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.DX_57.SR_57.HttpLoginFilter.doFilter(HttpLoginFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
]]
```

Can you help to fix this issue?

P.S I just noticed that there is a new configuration into the Glassfish web panel.

[image]

Any idea how I have to configure the panel in order to access Database resources.

Comment: Did you define the resource in glassfish?

Comment: I just noticed that there is a new configuration into the Glassfish 4 panel. Any idea how I can configure it?

Comment: You should use the node JDBC for you DataSource Problem. Check the jdbc/Oracle Resource. Does it point to the Oracle connection pool? Please select the node Oracle under JDBC Connection Pools. Can you Ping the server?

Comment: Yes, I can ping the server.

Comment: I can not give a proper answer with too few informations. However I would create the domain again and start using the default JDBC Resources first.